# Looking up e-mail address from a cell

Tags: excel, vba, email

I want to send an automated e-mail to an e-mail address which will be read from a defined cell in my outlook spreadsheet (Fixed... D,4 for instance).

I have attached the code below, can someone help me with this?

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
    Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OMail
        .Display
    End With

    With OMail
        .To = ""
        .Subject = "Feedback Form"
        .Display
    End With

    Set OMail = Nothing
    Set OApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the value from cell **`D4`** like this:

```
With OMail
    .To = Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Range("D4").Value
    .Subject = "Feedback Form"
    .Display
End With
```